# Android Device Owner QR Code provisioning disables Backup Service

Tags: android, provisioning, device-owner

I'm provisioning Android devices in Device-Owner mode via QR code. The device owner app is from our EMM tool (Ivanit EPM).
The Provisioning itself works fine, but the problem is, that after the provisioning the Backup Service is not accessible (greyed out).
But one of our customers, needs it to restore the contacts from the old devices.

I already searched a lot, and found something to enable Backup Service (see link below), but not with QR code method. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/package-summary

This is the QR code in Text with line breaks:

```
{ 'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME': 'afw.com.landesk.ldmsagent/com.landesk.ldmsagent.DeviceAdmin',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION': 'http://community.ivanti.com/downloads/patch/component/LD2016/android-AFW-prod.apk',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM': 'hOYijtSjVpTKDz1KT_TGoP8cPyDbH_nuxJkIzWpNn7E',
'android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION': true }
```

Does somebody has an ideas, how to get the Backup Service working again?
Is there a way with `android.app.extra.PROVISIONING`, or is there a way to give the settings from an xml or json or something?